# Update record on form inputs I want

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I am trying to make a profile sort of page. Where I would like it to show empty fields as a textfield, to do this I use the following code in my view.

```
$vNaam = $row->vNaam;
        if(empty($vNaam) && $this->uri->segment(3) == $this->session->userdata('username')){
            echo "<p>Voornaam: ";
            echo form_input('vNaam', $this->input->post('vNaam'));
            echo form_error('vNaam');
            echo "</P>";
        } else {
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<p>Voornaam: ";
            echo $vNaam;
            echo "</P>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
```

To proccess the data I use the following method in my controller.

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $data = array(
            'vNaam' => $this->input->post('vNaam')
        );
        $data=array_filter($data);
$this->model_users->update_info($data);
        redirect('main/profile/'. $this->session->userdata('username'));

    } else {

        $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getProfile($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->load->view('content_profile', $data);
    }
```

and finally my model.

```
function update_info($data){

    $this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->update('users',$data);

}
```

With this I am trying to make it so that it only updates the records that are not yet filled in.

Now when I create a new account on my website and fill out the form and update it works, but only once. Let's say I leave one of the fields blank, When i try to update the field again, nothing happens. It doesn't show a text field, but just an empty

tag. But the thing is, I want people to be able to add data as they please.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Describe your desired outcome and your current outcome. What is your Problem? And do describe that in an edit of your post so others can see it when they reads you question, rather than writing it in the comments which are harder to read and will less likely be seen.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain you this with the help of an example. But for this you have to keep your `input name` and database `field name` - same.

**1) Example table `users`**

```
id  |  name  |   email  |   mobile   |   address
```

**2) Your view**

```
<form action="/users/update" method="POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "name" />
    <input type = "email" name = "email" />
    <input type = "text" name = "mobile" />
    <input type = "text" name = "address" />
</form>
```

**3) Your controller**

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $data = array_filter($this->input->post(), 'strlen');  
        // Remove all empty values from array

       $this->user_model->update_details($data);
    }
}
```

**4) Your model**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
    }

    public function update_details($data)
    {
        /* 
        Now $data is a ready array to be update directly in your table
        which has all non-null values and also ready with columns name with it
        */

        $this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $this->db->update('users', $data);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

As you submit the form above with a blank value in `address`, the `array_filter` with `strlen` flag will remove the blank values from the `POST` array. Also since the `input names` are same to that of the table `field names`, you have made ready the array which you'll be using in your `update query`. The pass the `array` to the model and thats it. Hope it'll help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, thats exactly what I'm already doing. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In case of empty tag instead on an input field, there's something wrong in if...else. But it looks good to me. Check the condition getting true in case of empty field and don't know about the other condition whether it is giving true, since your are use && both the conditions have to be true. Try printing both the conditions and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this specific problem by removing my stupidly placed 'Required' validation rules on one of my fields, so that when I would try to update and the update didn't contain the field that was required, it failed. And since I was also stupid enough to not set any validation error outputs on my view I didn't notice. My apologies.